# Tengo una cosa que no se responder

Tags: replace, replaceall

Escribe un método que, dado un *String*, devuelve otro objeto *String* en el que
se cambian todas las vocales minúsculas del original por la letra 'a'. Escribe un
programa que permita comprobar el funcionamiento.

Tengo este ejercicio que no sé hacerlo bien, el código que llevo es este:

```
public class Ejercicio2 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String cadena = "Esto es una prueba del segundo ejercicio de Strings";
  
    System.out.println(cadena.replaceAll("e", "a"));
    System.out.println(cadena);
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, no sé que hacer para poder reemplazar a la vez **a, e, i, o, u** por la letra **a**.

Answer (score 0):

Una possible solucion, es que utilices Regex, son expresiones regulares que se pueden utilizar para describir cadenas y números de cadenas en una forma lógica general con el fin de buscarlas, sustituirlas, manipularlas, etc.

```
    String cadena = "Esto es una prueba del segundo ejercicio de Strings";
    System.out.println(cadena.replaceAll("[eiouEIOU]", "a"));
    System.out.println(cadena);
```

Si necesitas informacion: http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2013/07/ejemplos-expresiones-regulares-java-split.html